# error expected unqualified-id before numeric constant help me

Tags: button, arduino, numeric, led

This is my code to use a button:

```
int estado = 0

void setup(){
  pinMode(8, INPUT); 
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT)
}



void loop(){ 
  estado = digitalRead(8);
  if(estado == HIGH){
    digitalWrite(4, HIGH);  
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your eyes have failed you. Your first line is missing a terminating semicolon.

Comment: Also in the last line of the setup function.

Comment: Sure, but the compiler at least gives a sensible/sensical warning for that one.